Jetpack Compose @PreviewParameter Not Working Across Modules in Android
I'm working on a multi-module Kotlin Android Jetpack Compose project and facing an issue with the @PreviewParameter annotation not functioning correctly when used across modules.
Core module setup:
class PlayerPreviewParameterProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<List<Player>> {  
    override val values: Sequence<List<Player>> = sequenceOf(PlayerPreviewData.players)  
}

object PlayerPreviewData {
    val players: List<Player> = listOf(
        Player("1", "Player1", "Club1", PlayerAvatar.WOMAN_02, false, 1L),
        Player("2", "Player2", "Club2", PlayerAvatar.MAN_05, false, 2L),
        Player("3", "Player3", "Club3", PlayerAvatar.WOMAN_03, false, 3L),
        Player("4", "Player4", "Club4", PlayerAvatar.DEFAULT, false, 4L),
        Player("5", "Player5", "Club5", PlayerAvatar.WOMAN_04, false, 5L),
        Player("6", "Player6", "Club6", PlayerAvatar.MAN_04, false, 6L),
        Player("7", "Player7", "Club7", PlayerAvatar.WOMAN_05, false, 7L),
        Player("8", "Player8", "Club8", PlayerAvatar.DEFAULT, false, 8L),
        Player("9", "Player9", "Club9", PlayerAvatar.MAN_02, false, 9L),
    )
}

Player Management module setup:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun PlayerScreenPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(PlayerPreviewParameterProvider::class) players: List<Player>,
) {
    val width = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp
    val columns = when {
        width < COMPACT_WIDTH.dp -> 1
        else -> 2
    }

    BaseScreenPreview { scrollBehavior ->
        PlayerScreen(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            columns = columns,
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
            playersListUiState = Players(players),
            onPlayerUiEvent = {}
        )
    }
}

Error when running the preview:
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.tkirchmann.player_management.test, PID: 12402
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method de.tkirchmann.player_management.ui.routes.PlayerRouteKt.PlayerScreenPreview, parameter players
at de.tkirchmann.player_management.ui.routes.PlayerRouteKt.PlayerScreenPreview(Unknown Source:2)

The preview works fine when everything is in one module but fails when I try to use it across modules. The player management module imports the core, and the core module is independent.
Interestingly, the error log shows the process of the .test package, which I'm not actively using for these previews.
I'm using Compose BOM version "2024.05.00".
Has anyone faced similar issues or knows how to resolve the cross-module preview parameter problem in Jetpack Compose?
Thank you!
